# Change the Database Connection Dynamically in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, multi-tenant

I have the master database with login table and corresponding database settings for each user. On login I should dynamically change the db settings fetching from the table.
I can change the db connection but this is not persisting.

```
Config::set("database.connections.mysql", [
'driver' => 'mysql',
"host" => $usr_host,
"database" => $usr_database,
"username" => $usr_username,
"password" => $usr_password,
...
]);
```

edit: 
New database is  created for each user when he/she registers with the app and thus i dont have  the database connection for each user defined in the config/database.php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel: connect to databases dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085131/laravel-connect-to-databases-dynamically)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can use the default database for user login and have a new field for the database name. Then whenever you need to query a different database, you can just change your db connection.

Something like this

```
$someModel = new SomeModel;
$databaseName = "mysql2"; // Dynamically get this value from db
$someModel->setConnection($databaseName);
$something = $someModel->find(1);
```

You can read more about it here.
http://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections

Comment: what if im not working with model, and im using just ::table

Comment: Well this isnt elegant and wont recommend it, but an easier way of doing this would be to somehow change the returned array in app/config/database.php. So you add some condition if the condition is met then you return secondary db details else you always return primary db details.

Answer (score 12):

This way you can set new parameter when it comes to database:

```
 \Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', $schemaName);
```

Remember about `PURGE` to persist this settings

```
 DB::purge('mysql');
```

Cheers!

Comment: purge function of DB class is very useful.

Comment: Your answer is really helped me, thank you very much.

there is a case were we need to change only the connection database name as we might have the same connection but with multiple dbs

Answer (score 3):

you need to get the config first.. then alter the specific field then set it back..

```
$config = Config::get('database.connections.company');
$config['database'] = "company_tenant_$id";
$config['password'] = "test2123";
config()->set('database.connections.company', $config);
```

Comment: this settings changes to default in next request

Comment: where/which file will I have to do this? I am just lost. Please let me know the exact file path where I can do this. I just want to be able to do it once and then I should no longer have to do it every time in every class and container.

Comment: For the next who made it here, you configure the connection like @ZeroOne is doing. Then, you call the configured connection with the desired query, like this for example: 
`$users = \DB::connection('company')->table('users')->get();`

Answer (score 1):

I think a good place to change the database connection place is in `bootstrap/app.php` file, use the code below:

```
$app->afterBootstrapping(\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration::class, function ($ap) {
    // your database connection change may happens here
});
```

It is before ServiceProvider register and boot, so even if you use `DB` or `Eloquent` staff in ServiceProvider, it works very well.

Comment: But I need to check if the user is logged in then I want the use the dynamic db connection, else I want to use the default login database ( by which the user can only view the login page and nothing more )

Comment: I just tried your method. I really like to to do it your way. But inside that code block when I want to check if the user is logged in, it says that Auth class is not defined. How can I access the Auth class inside that code block? If I am just able to check if the user is logged in, then I will be all set for this.

Answer (score 0):

In laravel what you can do is create the different connections in the connections array of the file **conf/database**, then these connections you can use them when you are going to carry out operations in your application.

If you use **query builder** or **raw expresions** you must use the **connection ('name')** method to perform queries, for example:

```
$users = DB::connection('mysql')
         ->table('users')
         ->select(...)
         ->get();
```

If you use eloquent you can specify the name of the connection in the model file in the connection attribute, for example:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The connection name for the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $connection = 'mysql';
}
```

A solution to your problem could be that you have created the different types of connections according to the users in the file **conf/database**, and save the name of the connection that the user uses as a column in the user table, and when you go to make the queries you get the name of the connection of the user, for example:

```
$user = User::find(Auth::id());
$connection = $user->connection;

$users = DB::connection($connection)
                      ->table('users')
                      ->select(...)
                      ->get ();
```

more info:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#read-and-write-connections

Answer (score 0):

After an extensive search I found it this way:

Go to this file **vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate.php**

Go to the method: **protected function authenticate($request, array $guards)**
and right after the method has started, paste the following code:

```
    if(auth()->check() && !empty( auth()->user()->db_name )){

        $dynamic_db_name = auth()->user()->db_name;
        $config = \Config::get('database.connections.mysql');
        $config['database'] = $dynamic_db_name;
        $config['password'] = "Your DB Password";
        config()->set('database.connections.mysql', $config);
        \DB::purge('mysql');
    }
```

first we are checking if the user is logged in with

```
auth()->check()
```

Then as you may have added db_name name or the like column table to your users table according to each user. So in the next condition, I am making sure that the db_name is available:

```
&& !empty( auth()->user()->db_name )
```

Then after execution enters the if condition I get the db_name from the user record and set the configuration according to the user database, save the config and use purge method of DB class to persist this setting.
I was really stuck with it. I did not wanted to change my db connection in every class. So this is how I got it. Now I can use both Eloquent and DB without any tension anywhere. In my application I have one centeral database for login of all users and then for each organization there is a different database. So after the user has logged in, I do not need the centeral database (login database), I juse need the user/organization specific database. So this is how I got it to work.