# How to run migrations for multiple databases in laravel?

Tags: laravel, migration

I am using laravel-8 ,i have multiple databases for that i configured in database.php as like follows

```
 'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => '',
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME',''),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => ''
        ],
'databaselist'=>[
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => 'databaselist',
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME',''),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => ''
        ],
```

Generally my application works when user logs in at that time will place database name in `mysql.database` like this we are using.

Now i am facing a scenario i am going to start migrations and i need to run migrations in all databases so for that i am using $connection property so i need to loop it database list connection and pass database name to `mysql.database` and run in that database.can anyone help me to achieve this scenario

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateTestTable extends Migration
{
    public $connection ='mysql';
    
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('test_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->id();
           $table->string('name');
        });
    }

   
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('test_table');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Schema::connection() to run migrations on different databases so a loop though the connections name would probably achieve this.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateTestTable extends Migration
{
    
    public function up()
    {
        $connections = $this->getConnections();

        foreach($connections as $connection) {
            Schema::connection($connection->name)->create('test_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->id();
                $table->string('name');
            });

        }
    }

    public function down()
    {
        $connections = $this->getConnections();

        foreach($connections as $connection) {
            Schema::connection($connection->name)->dropIfExists('test_table');
        }
    }

    public function getConnections()
    {
        $connections = TestTable::connection('databaselist')->get();

        foreach($connections as $connection) {
            Config::set("database.connections.$connection->name", [
                'driver' => 'mysql',
                "host" => "$connection->host",
                "database" => "$connection->database",
                "username" => "$connection->username",
                "password" => "$connection->password",
                "port" => $connection->port,
                'charset'   => 'utf8',
                'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
                'prefix'    => '',
                'strict'    => false,
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit

You can get the connections like you would any other models data then you will probably have to set them in the config in order to be able to run them.

This Question might be of some use as well, once's you retrieve the values

[Change the Database Connection Dynamically in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46775265/change-the-database-connection-dynamically-in-laravel)

Comment: But my question is i need to fetch all  database names from databaselist connection and i need to put those names to mysql configuration

Comment: Edited my answer, i haven't tested this but something along those lines might be a start for you. You will have to set the connections when you retrieve them of you will not be able to run the connection part

Comment: i tried to debug but before going to enter any function it's showing NO DATABASE SELECTED issue

Comment: SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected (SQL: create table `migrations` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `migration` varchar(255) not null, `batch` int not null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

Comment: Create table migrations migrations is your default migration and not the migration i have wrote, Have you migrated to the database mysql to create these yet

Comment: Not yet migrated,This is the first time i am trying to migrate