# Laravel 5.5 dynamic db name

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, connection

In my app, there is a user registration part and each user have u nickname. So I need to create a db, with the specific name for each user. How can I implement dynamic db connection in my app.

Comment: you want to create a separate database for each user?

Comment: yes it looks like that @laravellevaral

Comment: yes I want that the each user have a separate db

Comment: just for clarification, you want each user to have their own database not their own tables, right? I just want to make sure you didn't confuse database and table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel: connect to databases dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085131/laravel-connect-to-databases-dynamically)