# Laravel 5.6 change database connection in the runtime permanently

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5.6

I have two databases. The second database changes dynamically, i.e. each client has its own database so the database name and password are different but the architecture is the same for all clients. So I have two model groups, the first for the first database and the second for the second database. Indeed, the second model group must be able to make queries to the client database and not to the default database

so I want to set the default database connection dynamically.`Config::Set()` will do it for one request only. I want it for every subsequent request.

I use the Laravel Framework, you know of a clean solution that might solve my problem and help others interested

thanks to everyone for your help

Comment: You can update the the value of config. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/configuration#accessing-configuration-values or write it to file and access it.

Comment: One way would be deploy the app several times and keep separate `.env` files for each client. For one model group use the default connection for the second group on each model put `protected $connection = 'seconddb';` and keep changing connection params for `seconddb` in `.env` file. The downside would be different domains/subdomains

Comment: @SougataBose yes, i set the config, it will do it for one request only.

Comment: @MichalBieda I thought the same idea, but it is not a good solution because if I have many clients I should do many manipulation and imagine you if I have to update the application, it will take me a lot of time

Comment: I recommend you to read the following `Laravel doc` to understand how requests work. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/lifecycle

Comment: Have you tried setting the config value inside of a global middleware?

Comment: @user3158900 no I haven't tried, I want when we change the database remains permanent.

Comment: @Jackowski I'll read later, Thank

Comment: @diego Suggestion:Try to different environment for each client and set their database connections accordingly in their environment files.

Comment: this answer may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085131/laravel-connect-to-databases-dynamically

Answer (score 2):

Create two entries in `config/database.php`:

```
'connections' => array(

    # Connection one
    'mysql_1' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql_1',
        'host'      => 'host_1',
        'database'  => 'db_1',
        'username'  => 'username_1',
        'password'  => 'password_1'
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),

    # Connection two
    'mysql_2' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql_2',
        'host'      => 'host_2',
        'database'  => 'db_2',
        'username'  => 'username_2',
        'password'  => 'password_2'
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),
),
```

Create a base model or a Trait for each group of models which sets the connection at the model level. Change all your models to extends from their respective base model.

**Base Models**

```
class BaseGroupOneModel extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'mysql_1';
}

class BaseGroupTwoModel extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'mysql_2';
}
```

**Traits**

```
trait GroupOneTrait
{
    protected $connection = 'mysql_1';
}

trait GroupTwoTrait
{
    protected $connection = 'mysql_2';
}

class GroupOneModel extends Model
{
    use app/Models/Traits/GroupOneTrait;
}

class GroupTwoModel extends Model
{
    use app/Models/Traits/GroupTwoTrait;
}
```

Comment: Also, you can use `Middleware` to detect your client and change database connection as required with `config()` helper. `config()->set('database.default', yourconnectionname);`

Comment: @Pusparaj I'm trying to implement this solution [https://github.com/uxweb/laravel-multi-db]

Comment: The solution is you gave me is cool but you don't take into account that the connection name of the second model group changes for each user

Comment: Create a middleware, apply logic to detect connection name according to logged in user (or as per your requirement) and add the new middleware to all routes via Kernel.php