# Changing MySQL database to connect to based on URL parameter in Laravel 8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a series of databases named server_1 to server_100. Based on the URL parameter that the users select, I would like to connect to that database. Is there a way to accomplishing this without defining 100 separate connections in .env?

Comment: Exposing actual db name in frontend is a major security vulnerability.

Comment: You can use ```tenancy``` concept in laravel https://tenancy.dev/

Comment: It must help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085131/laravel-connect-to-databases-dynamically

Comment: Or you can define all the db connection into databases. And based on url changes. By using middleware you can set the connection dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change database connection on fly and also dont forget to purge connection.

```
Config::set("database.connections.mysql.host", "127.0.0.1");
Config::set("database.connections.mysql.database", "database_name");
Config::set("database.connections.mysql.username", "username");
Config::set("database.connections.mysql.password", "password");
DB::purge('mysql');
```

Comment: Are the configurations saved until script execution is complete, or is it saved until the DB is purged again?

Comment: It must require to purge connection, when ever you change.