# Change database dynamically according to user login

Tags: php, laravel, database, vue.js, laravel-8

Currently I am Creating SaaS online inventory software in Laravel 8 as backend and Vuejs 2 as frontend.

When User Login get database name and database password from master database according to User Email is Done.

Now I am trying to change database but the database is not changing from master database to user database for all Model and Controllers.

My Question is how can I change database connection according to user login?

Comment: Maybe consider usaing this [multitenancy package](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-multitenancy/v2/introduction) from Spatie. It provides such functionality without you having to code it all yourself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel: connect to databases dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085131/laravel-connect-to-databases-dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

In laravel8 defines multiple connections in your **config/database.php** configuration file, you may access each connection via the connection method provided by the DB facade.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

$users = DB::connection('anther-db')->select(...);
```